# Combine two headphone-microphone splitters?

Tags: audio, microphone, splitter

I want to connect a game console's audio output to my computer's audio input using a 3.5-mm headphone-microphone splitter. The output will be connected to the input (microphone) on the splitter. I'm thinking about buying a headset, but it comes with two 3.5-mm connectors, one for the headphone and another for the microphone. If I buy another headphone-microphone splitter, connect the headset to it, and then connect the splitter to the output (headphone) on the first splitter, will it work?

I'm going to record audio from the game console and my voice when I speak into the microphone on the headset. I also want to hear the audio from the game console through the headset.

Answer (score 2):

The headset splitter only takes care of connecting the right wires to the right wires. Connecting headset splitters in a series has no sense to work.

I'm not sure what type of headset you have (computer headset, phone headset), and why you want to do with the audio feed. But what you have to pay attention to:

1. A 3.5mm headset jack (found on phones) is NOT the same as a 3.5mm  combined mic+audio jack (found on laptops).If your computer has a combined microphone + audio out 3.5 jack
   connector, you cannot use a phone-headset with it. It is not like a
   mobile phone jack connector, which can use a headset. This jack can
   EITHER take input from a microphone, or EITHER give audio output to
   an earphone. If you have a headset splitter, it will give you two
   plugs, a microphone and an audio connector. If your computer has two
   jacks (one for audio, one for mic), you can use both (see picture).
   If you computer has only one jack, you can only use it for one
   feature (mic or audio).
2. A microphone input expects a low signal (weak, from a microphone), while the audio output is a high signal (strong). You should connect the audio output to a proper line-in signal. If you connect the audio out to a mic-in, you can damage the electronics easily, so be very careful with the volume.
3. You can use stereo Y-splitters to feed the audio to parallel sources (for example to feed the audio out to the speakers and headphones at the same time). To to the same with the mic signal, you need mono Y-splitters.

If you don't have a line-in connector on your computer, my suggestion is to by an external USB soundcard for your computer, which has a proper audio line-in.

Another important point is that phone-headset-splitters tend to be "brand" specific, depending on the connector used (iPhone, Nokia Legacy, Android, Windows Phone).

[image: Headset splitter for phone headsets.]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The warning about connecting a high-signal (audio output) to a weak signal (mic in) was super useful. I was planning to connect my guitar amp's headphone out to a Mac Mini's headset plug using a splitter. Do you think it will work if I keep the volume low?